# Ajustar Section [Position: absolute]

Tags: html, css, div, posicionamento

Gente,

estou fazendo um site como projeto da faculdade, porém estou apanhando um pouco para resolver um problema com as posições dos elementos.
Tenho 3 sections, uma ajustada para ser Cabeçalho, uma ajustada para ser Conteúdo e uma ajustada para ser Rodapé.
O cabeçalho e Rodapé possuem o atributo "position: absolute" porém, gostaria de fazer com que o conteúdo começe abaixo do cabeçalho e termine antes do rodapé sem ter que ajustar tamanho para eles.

Como está agora:
[image: Como está]

Como quero que fique:
[image: Como quero]

A linha vermelha representa o tamanho da section.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a unidade `vh` para definir a altura do container como 100% de forma estática (pode ser relativo também), e usar flexbox para distribuir os elemento em topo, meio e rodapé com `justify-content: space-between` e `flex-direction: column`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.ctn {  
  background: #cecece;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#header {
  background: #424242;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#content {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
#footer {
  background: #424242;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctn">

  <section id="header">Header</section>
    <section id="content">
      content <br>
      content <br>
      content <br>
      content <br>
      content <br>
      content <br>
    </section>
  <section id="footer">Footer</section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a sua intenção em colocar `position:absolute` seja de manter o `header` e o `footer` sempre parados no mesmo lubar. Então fiz um exemplo com o `main` ocupando 100% da altura disponível, e com `overflow:auto`, assim apenas o `main` vai ter `scroll` e os outros elementos sempre fica posicionas no `top` e no `bottom`.

Veja como fica:

**OBS:** Execute tb como "Página toda" para ver como o `footer` se comporta quando o conteúdo não é grande o suficiente pro `scroll` aparecer

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam ipsam repellat eos animi officia qui, quia amet accusamus, fugit eius consectetur mollitia. Atque ea veritatis expedita dolorem unde? Alias, nihil? Assumenda quaerat officiis animi ipsum ut aliquam, consectetur dignissimos facilis impedit, est enim perspiciatis voluptas ea dolore velit accusamus cupiditate numquam amet mollitia asperiores recusandae laborum qui debitis iste! Aliquid veniam quibusdam aperiam sequi, quae porro ab et illo dolor nulla voluptatem, suscipit sapiente quos dicta tempora eius placeat cumque molestiae culpa nam reprehenderit? Suscipit animi, assumenda obcaecati nobis magnam esse enim deserunt libero ullam, omnis facilis accusantium, fuga molestias reiciendis. Recusandae aspernatur, magnam beatae at debitis, enim quam, quod ea maxime exercitationem nesciunt nisi. Consectetur provident quidem sequi temporibus esse nostrum eius obcaecati quam autem quae quo illo facere architecto iste nesciunt, aliquam delectus dignissimos inventore ab, excepturi dolorem quia quibusdam. Culpa cum amet ducimus, commodi quisquam laudantium in rem mollitia qui impedit odit ex neque laboriosam repellat, inventore eaque doloribus accusamus quod error! Dolorem, libero id laboriosam deserunt dolore fugiat quo at explicabo asperiores dicta sequi nemo quidem ab distinctio molestiae, accusamus, reiciendis qui atque blanditiis mollitia incidunt! Natus temporibus eum sint libero saepe aspernatur, atque animi? Mollitia?
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```